# Uninstall Postgres ODBC/JDBC driver on Mac (iOS). Error: "Current transaction is aborted" (Tableau)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, odbc, tableau-api

I am getting the following error on Tableau:

```
"ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; Error while executing the query"
```

I reinstalled the latest version of PostgreSQL (13.3) as recommended in this [article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/Error-error-Current-Transaction-Is-Aborted-Commands-Ignored-Until-End-Of-Transaction-Block-Error-While-Executing-The-Query-when-connecting-or-interacting-with-Postgresql-Data-Source?_gl=1*iseb25*_ga*MTI2Mzg3ODczOS4xNjIyODA4NjQ4*_ga_8YLN0SNXVS*MTYyMzMzNjY1Ni45LjEuMTYyMzMzNjY5OC4w&_ga=2.42983781.1142950855.1622808648-1263878739.1622808648) but I get the same error

I think I have the wrong Postgres ODBC driver installed and I need to uninstall it. There may also be a problem with how the JDBC driver is installed.

How can I uninstall Postgres ODBC/JDBC driver on Mac (iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem & issue was with the driver.

I downloaded the driver from : https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers?_ga=2.40526434.1567909167.1642407920-2139636933.1641279633
and placed it in the Driver folder(~Library/Tableau/Drivers).

This resolved my issue.